# fullcalendar not showing same events on agendaDay as agendaWeek

Tags: fullcalendar

I have a really basic knowledge of javascript and have a simple FullCalendar setup on my site. I am using agendaWeek for my main site, but I want to use agendaDay, or even basicDay for my mobile site but when I switch to agendaDay or basicDay it cuts off the events at the end of the day, seemingly past 5pm. (here's the implementation of the mobile site vs main site: http://www.absolutemma.com/schedule.php and http://www.absolutemma.com/mobile/schedule.html) and the javascript I'm using on the mobile page:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                // put your options and callbacks here
                header: {
                },
                titleFormat: {
                    day: 'M/d/yyyy'   //whatever date format you want here
                },
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            events: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/absolutemma%40gmail.com/public/basic',
            currentTimezone:'America/Denver',
            height: 750,
            minTime: 10,
            maxTime: 24
            })
        });
    </script>
```

Am I missing a callback to tell agendaDay to display events after a certain time? Did accidentally a word somewhere?

Comment: I can see all time-slots from 10 AM to 12 AM on the mobile site. Did you fix the issue?

Comment: Yeah, those are showing up correctly. I have some time slots for 6pm-7:30pm and 7:30pm-9pm which aren't showing up, though.

Comment: I now see events appearing on your site in the 7:30pm - 9pm range.  Did you have other issues you're seeing or have you figured it out?

Comment: They are for the main site, but not the mobile site.

Comment: The main site is using agendaWeek, the mobile site is using agendaDay. It seems that any of the 'Day' (agendaDay and basicDay) options do not show events after 5pm.

Comment: I still have not figured this out.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue - any developments?